# Angular — an undocumented child-to-parent communication?

Tags: javascript, angular

After reading this [*section about component interaction*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#) — I've noticed that there is another way of communicating from child to parent ( which wasn't really documented there) :

It turns out that **if** I have a parent class :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <my-item></my-item>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  go1()
   {
     alert(2)
   }
  constructor() {}
}
```

And in the child component -  I Inject a `parent` type into the ctor :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-item',
  template: `
    <div>
     <input type="button" value='invoke parent method' (click) = "myGo()"/>
    </div>
  `,
})
  class MyItem {
  name:string;
  private parent1 : App; 

  myGo()
  {
    this.parent1.go1()    //<--- access is available here
  } 

  constructor(private parent1 : App) 
   {
    this.parent1 = parent1; //<------------ manually, unlike service
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
   }
}
```

Then Angular sees that i'm trying to inject a parent type class and it gives me access to it.

The click works of course.

**Question:**

Beside other alternatives which I already know , is it documented anywhere ? or is it just a feature that I can't rely on it

[**plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/MM5p87yLo4wOLLvMM4G6?p=preview)

Comment: If it's not documented, I wouldn't rely on it. It can be changed in the next minor release without it being listed as a breaking change...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works well and can be used.

A major downside is, that it breaks encapsulation.
The child component needs to know about the parent component.
This approach makes the child tightly coupled to it's parent, which is usually considered a bad thing because it prevents the component to be re-used anywhere within your application, because it now only works as a child of this exact parent.

Comment: Agree. Just wanted to know if it's safe to use ( since it's not documented). thank you.

Comment: Besides that it's safe. If you have a `TabPanel` component and a `TabComponent` that is only supposed to be used with `TabPanel`, there is IMHO nothing that speaks against using this approach.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer anything that's undocumented can be changed without notification, I wouldn't think that's something that can be relied on.

Comment: That you can inject a parent might not be documented well, but you can rely that it won't change without a strong reason and also not without a bump in the major version number.